# Subquery: how to retrieve the last non-zero value from a column?

Tags: sql

Considering a table customerBalance with 3 columns: name, date and balance. Suppose a set of records like:

```
cus_name    cus_date    cus_balance
John        06/14/2011  1000
John        06/15/2011   500
John        06/16/2011     0
Mary        06/14/2011  3000
Mary        06/15/2011  2800
Mary        06/16/2011     0
```

How to create a SQL query which returns, for the date 6/16/2011 instead 0, the last non-zero value based on date (in sample, $500 for John and $2800 for Mary)?

I'm trying to do it using a subquery which uses Max function to retrieve the last date with non-zero value, but I didn't succeed. This example is quite "nonsensical", but I really need to do an operation like this in my dataset. Thanks!

Comment: What if you 1000 on 17th June for Mary? Or will date be a parameter? And what Db/version too please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: If you can specify the DB and version this query can be improved.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM customers
 WHERE (cus_name, cus_date) 
        IN 
        (
            SELECT cus_name, MAX(cus_date)
              FROM customers
             WHERE cus_balance <> 0
             GROUP BY cus_name
        )
```

Update: Alternate version:

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM customers a,
            (
                SELECT cus_name, MAX(cus_date)
                    FROM customers
                 WHERE cus_balance <> 0
                 GROUP BY cus_name
            ) b
 WHERE a.cus_name = b.cus_name
   AND a.cus_date = b.cus_date
```

Comment: It looks great, but unfortunatelly I'm using the "ancient" Access 2000 and the syntax isn't working properly. Have you another approach?

Comment: @darth: I have added an alternate version to the post(not tested though). Pls try it..

Comment: I was doing something like your second version before asking, and I had the same error message from Access as when I implemented your code, which should be something like it in English: "You did a subquery which can return more than one field without using the reserved word EXISTS in FROM clause in main query. Review the SELECT instruction in the subquery so that it requires only one field". Boring, but I couldn't resolve it yet.

Comment: @darth: I ran the second query in Access 2007 and it ran fine.. I got the error that you mentioined for the first version? Can you check

Comment: worked fine. I did some adjustments because my table schema is a little bit more complex than this example, and also I've used the "First" statement for selecting the "Balance" value from subquery. Thanks a lot for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
CREATE Table #temp
(
    Cus_Name VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    Cus_Date Char(8) NULL,
    Cus_Balance INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('John' , '20110614' ,1000 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('John' , '20110615' , 500 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('John' , '20110616' ,   0 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Mary' , '20110614' ,3000 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Mary' , '20110615' ,2800 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Mary' , '20110616' ,   0 )

SELECT 
    T.Cus_Name ,
    MIN(t.Cus_Balance)
FROM #temp t 
WHERE t.Cus_Balance <>0
GROUP BY t.Cus_Name

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Raj Jayaswal, but I can't use this approach for more than one million records like in my case. Regards.