# How to retrieve "last" non-zero values from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Considering an ordered table with 11 columns:
`timespan, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9 and val10`

Suppose a set of records like:

```
timespan     val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9  val10
10/09/2011      0     0    60    80    40     0     0    40    80      0
10/10/2011      0    10    90    30    70    50    50    70    30     90
10/11/2011     10     0    20     0     0    60    60     0     0     20
```

I need a SQL query (for SQL Server 2012) which returns the last (in time) non zero values for all columns, val1, val2, ..., that is,

```
val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9  val10
  10    10    20    30    70    60    60    70    30     20
```

A similar question can be found at [**Subquery: how to retrieve the last non-zero value from a column?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377108/subquery-how-to-retrieve-the-last-non-zero-value-from-a-column) but it only works for one column and the generalisation to include more columns (as in this case) seems not practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct first_value(val1) over (order by sign(val1) desc, timespan desc) as val1,
       first_value(val2) over (order by sign(val2) desc, timespan desc) as val2,
       . . .
from t;
```

Generally, I am opposed to using `select distinct` as a replacement for an aggregation query.  Unfortunately, SQL Server supports `first_value()` as a window function but does not provide an equivalent for aggregation.

Note:  the `sign()` function is used to put the zero values last.  If you can have negative values, then use `abs(sign())`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a quick unpivot followed by a pivot

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
           Select top 1 with ties item,value
            From  YourTable
            UnPivot ( Value for Item in (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10) ) u
            Where value<>0
            Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By item Order by timespan desc)
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) For item in (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10) ) p
```

**Returns**

```
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9    val10
10      10      20      30      70      60      60      70      30      20
```

Comment: @scsimon Thanks,  pure dumb luck that it supports pre-2012.  To be honest, I never even considered that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. 
1. logic is to first unpivot values and then remove 0 entries and then calculate last non zero value as row_num=1.

2. Followed by pivoting again to get the result.

Query is below

```
create table t
(timespan date,val1 int,val2 int,val3 int,val4 int,val5 int,val6 int,val7 int,val8 int,val9 int,val10 int);
insert into t values
('10/09/2011', 0, 0,60,80,40, 0, 0,40,80, 0)
,('10/10/2011', 0,10,90,30,70,50,50,70,30,90)
,('10/11/2011',10, 0,20, 0, 0,60,60, 0, 0,20);

select * 
    from
(
    select 
        value, Columns 
    from
    (
        select 
            timespan,
            value, 
            Columns, 
            row_number() over(partition by Columns order by timespan desc) r
        from
        (select * from t)s
        unpivot
        ( 
            value for Columns in 
                ([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4],[val5],[val6],[val7],[val8],[val9],[val10])
        )up
        where value<>0
    ) t 
    where r=1
 )s
pivot
(
    max(value) for Columns in 
        ([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4],[val5],[val6],[val7],[val8],[val9],[val10])
)p
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/OBU68285)**</kbd>